# Issue in booting Xen DomU Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, virtualization, xen

I am trying to run Mainline linux kernel v5.4.0-rc3 as DomU. My setup details below.

```
Target hw: Pine64+
Architecture: aarch64 (arm64)
Xen version: 4.6.5
Dom0: Mainline linux Kernel v5.4.0-rc3
```

DomU config file:

```
kernel = "path to kernel image"
memory = "128"
name = "domU"
vcpus = 1
disk = [ 'phy:/dev/loop0,xvda,w' ]
extra = "earlyprintk=xenboot console=hvc0 root=/dev/xvda debug rw init=/bin/sh"
```

I loaded the DomU as below.

```
ubuntu@LXC_NAME:~/workspace/domu$ sudo losetup /dev/loop0 rootfs.ext4
ubuntu@LXC_NAME:~/workspace/domu$ sudo xl -vvv create -d domu.config
```

But DomU boot failed with following message.

```
libxl: debug: libxl_device.c:337:libxl__device_disk_set_backend: Disk vdev=xvda spec.backend=phy
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:639:libxl__ev_xswatch_register: watch w=0x238e0bd0 wpath=/local/domain/0/backend/vbd/1/51712/state token=3/0: register slotnum=3
libxl: debug: libxl_create.c:1586:do_domain_create: ao 0x238de720: inprogress: poller=0x238de7b0, flags=i
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:576:watchfd_callback: watch w=0x238e0bd0 wpath=/local/domain/0/backend/vbd/1/51712/state token=3/0: event epath=/local/domain/0/backend/vbd/1/51712/state
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:884:devstate_callback: backend /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/1/51712/state wanted state 2 still waiting state 1
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:576:watchfd_callback: watch w=0x238e0bd0 wpath=/local/domain/0/backend/vbd/1/51712/state token=3/0: event epath=/local/domain/0/backend/vbd/1/51712/state
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:880:devstate_callback: backend /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/1/51712/state wanted state 2 ok
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:677:libxl__ev_xswatch_deregister: watch w=0x238e0bd0 wpath=/local/domain/0/backend/vbd/1/51712/state token=3/0: deregister slotnum=3
libxl: debug: libxl_device.c:991:device_backend_callback: calling device_backend_cleanup
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:691:libxl__ev_xswatch_deregister: watch w=0x238e0bd0: deregister unregistered
libxl: error: libxl.c:1991:libxl__get_domid: failed to get own domid (domid)
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:1041:device_hotplug: Failed to get domid
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:691:libxl__ev_xswatch_deregister: watch w=0x238e0cd0: deregister unregistered
libxl: error: libxl_create.c:1176:domcreate_launch_dm: unable to add disk devices
libxl: error: libxl.c:1991:libxl__get_domid: failed to get own domid (domid)
libxl: error: libxl_device.c:849:libxl__initiate_device_remove: unable to get my domid
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:691:libxl__ev_xswatch_deregister: watch w=0x238d9210: deregister unregistered
libxl: error: libxl.c:1991:libxl__get_domid: failed to get own domid (domid)
libxl: error: libxl.c:1684:devices_destroy_cb: libxl__devices_destroy failed for 1
libxl: debug: libxl.c:1738:devices_destroy_cb: forked pid 679 for destroy of domain 1
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:1874:libxl__ao_complete: ao 0x238de720: complete, rc=-3
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:1843:libxl__ao__destroy: ao 0x238de720: destroy
libxl: debug: libxl.c:1477:libxl_domain_destroy: ao 0x238d8a90: create: how=(nil) callback=(nil) poller=0x238de7b0
libxl: error: libxl.c:1610:libxl__destroy_domid: non-existant domain 1
libxl: error: libxl.c:1568:domain_destroy_callback: unable to destroy guest with domid 1
libxl: error: libxl.c:1495:domain_destroy_cb: destruction of domain 1 failed
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:1874:libxl__ao_complete: ao 0x238d8a90: complete, rc=-21
libxl: debug: libxl.c:1486:libxl_domain_destroy: ao 0x238d8a90: inprogress: poller=0x238de7b0, flags=ic
libxl: debug: libxl_event.c:1843:libxl__ao__destroy: ao 0x238d8a90: destroy
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: total allocations:97 total releases:97
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: current allocations:0 maximum allocations:3
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: cache current size:3
xc: debug: hypercall buffer: cache hits:87 misses:3 toobig:7
```

[DomU Complete boot log](https://pastebin.com/kU59vNNg)

xl list confirms that domU is not created.

```
ubuntu@LXC_NAME:~/workspace/domu$ sudo xl list
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs  State   Time(s)
(null)                                       0   256     2     r-----       9.8
```

I am finding difficult to understand the root cause of this issue. Could anyone throw light on what went wrong?

[Xen boot log](https://pastebin.com/HXU0mCkD)

Comment: I am still struggling with understanding the issue. It would be very much helpful, if anyone show me the problem. If the question needs more clarification, editing, kindly let me know specifically.

Comment: I doubt you\`ll find an answer on SO. It would be wiser to try other StackExchange subforums like [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) and [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

While loading the drive on creation and while accessing the instance are same ? , if so can you attach another disk to the domain and try accessing the same domain.

For example to attach it to the Domain Using the below :

```
xm block-attach Domain-0 file:/home/xen/vmdisk0 xvda w
```

and then modify the same in the config file and then run:

```
disk=['file:/home/xen/vmdisk0,xvda,w']
```

There are some additional parameters than can be mentioned in the file "builder" (domain build function), device_model and if you are using the physical disk drive you should mention `/dev/sdb`

If you are using a physical image to load as mentioned above you have to use something like this : `disk = [ 'file:/home/XEN_MI.img,hda,w']`